# Description Resource Path Location Type

Tags: java, spring

When i have added jpa dependency I got this error.Can anybody explain this ? 
Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: '/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar' in project

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a property of storing metadata of the jar you wished when you first declare the dependency without any actual jar. This causes some problems. To get around this you delete the whole .m2 repository and try to mvn clean install. Downloading a corrupted dependency jar might also be another possibility for your problem. If the problem still persists you can go to that folder and try to open it with any archive tool.

Comment: Thank you. @Deadpool  I tried but That's not working.

Comment: Can you show me the error screenshot along with the details of the editor you are using.

Comment: I think , It depends Linux mint  I reinstall Ubuntu so there is no problem now. Thanks for your helping.